# Magento place order button fails after PayPal express checkout is accepted

Tags: magento, error-handling, payment-gateway

I am doing a Magento build. I have just used a template and very basic extensions at this stage.

I get this error after testing with a PayPal payment.

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Address.php on line 95

And if I don't use PayPal in advance and log in it just lets me press the "Place Order" button, says it is processing the order but then doesn't change pages. The order does not drop into the back end but it does reduce my stock levels for the item. Does anyone know what this is? I have checked my mbstring is turned on as one other site recommended that.